# Spring4 & Tiles3 config programatically error: Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException:

Tags: java, configuration, spring-4, tiles-3

I need Your help.

I am trying to configure Spring4 to work with Tiles3. But I would like to be done with no xml.
I've done some configuration already:

```
package com.derp.common.init;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration.Dynamic;

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

public class Initializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {


    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(WebAppConfig.class);
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(ctx));

        ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);

        Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
        servlet.addMapping("/");
        servlet.setAsyncSupported(true);     
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        // Allow to use Put and Delete method for REST architecture
        registerHiddenFieldFilter(servletContext);
    }

    private void registerHiddenFieldFilter(ServletContext aContext) {
        aContext.addFilter("hiddenHttpMethodFilter", new HiddenHttpMethodFilter()).addMappingForUrlPatterns(null ,true, "/*"); 
    }
}
```

end:

```
package com.derp.common.init;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.tiles.Attribute;
import org.apache.tiles.Definition;
import org.apache.tiles.definition.UnresolvingLocaleDefinitionsFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ContentNegotiationConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.*;


@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.derp")
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER = "db.driver";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD = "db.password";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL = "db.url";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME = "db.username";

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "hibernate.dialect";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "hibernate.show_sql";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO = "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN_SERVICES = "services.entitymanager.packages.to.scan";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN_COMMON = "common.entitymanager.packages.to.scan";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN_CMS = "cms.entitymanager.packages.to.scan";

    @Resource
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        //sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN));
        sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {
                env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN_SERVICES),
                env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN_COMMON),
                env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN_CMS)
                });
        sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibProperties());
        return sessionFactoryBean;
    }

    private Properties hibProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL));
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO));
        return properties;  
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

//  @Bean
//  public UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
//      UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
//      resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
//      resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
//      resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
//      return resolver;
//  }
    @Bean
    public TilesViewResolver getTilesViewResolver() {
        TilesViewResolver tilesViewResolver = new TilesViewResolver();
        /*
         * tilesViewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
         * tilesViewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
         */
        tilesViewResolver.setViewClass(TilesView.class);
        return tilesViewResolver;
    }
    @Bean
    public TilesConfigurer getTilesConfigurer() {
        TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer = new TilesConfigurer();
        tilesConfigurer.setCheckRefresh(true);
        //tilesConfigurer.setDefinitions(new String[] { "/WEB-INF/tiles.xml" });
        return tilesConfigurer;
    }
    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.defaultContentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
                .mediaType("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .mediaType("xml", MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                .favorPathExtension(true); // default is true. just for clarity
    }
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/*").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/css/*");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/*").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/js/*");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/img/*").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/img/*");
    }
}
```

But I am getting an error:

`at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No URL for ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/tiles.xml]`

`Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/tiles.xml] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getURL(ServletContextResource.java:156)`

The errors occur cause I dont have the file tiles.xml.

I would like to do that config using Java Coniguration.

How can I achive this?

Comment: What makes you think that Tiles can be configured without a tiles definition file somewhere?

Comment: I hope so cause I hate xml configurations. So can it be configurated without xml?

Comment: if not? can You give me at least xml configuration help?

Comment: you can programmatically create your definitions. read the tiles documentation.

Comment: http://springbybhimu.blogspot.ro/2015/01/spring-4-and-tiles-3-programmatic.html check this tutorial to integrate spring 4 and tiles 3 programmatically

Comment: I've give up on tiles. I've moved to Thymeleaf. For now I cant check it, but thanks.